# Mesmo número de caracteres no password depois do md5

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou fazendo um processo de abrir uma modal e cadastrar um usuário.
A senha do usuário é modificada para `md5()`;

Após isto a senha fica com `32 caracteres`.

Quando o usuário vai carregar os dados do usuário para fazer um update.

Se a senha fosse:

```
123456
****** <- 6 caracteres
```

Mostraria no input:

```
*************************** <- 32 caracteres
```

Teria alguam forma de saber a quantidade que eram antes de fazer o `md5()`, ou talvez uma abordagem melhor.

Seria inviavel armazenar a quantidade de caracteres no `db` para realizar isto.

Comment: No update o correto não seria solicitar a senha para o usuário como confirmação? Trazer do banco não é uma boa ideia.
MD5 já não é mais segura também, devido aos ataques de dicionario, talvez valha a pena considerar usar outro método.

Comment: O ideal é não exibir a senha preenchida, eu costumo deixar o campo de senha bloqueada e um checkbox para habilitar esse campo, caso ele queira atualizar a senha, ele cadastra uma nova senha.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann um usuário Administrador poderia alterar a senha de um usuário de nivel inferior sem a necessidade de conhecer a senha do usuário. qual outro metodo você indicaria ?

Comment: Em qualquer site, o formulário de atualização de senha vem com **valor vazio** ou uma **quantidade fixa de asteriscos**. O que você quer fazer de exibir a quantidade de caracteres da senha é uma falha de segurança. Questão relacionada: [Como descriptografar MD5?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41517/13561)

Comment: @JefersonAssis eu gostaria  de poder mostrar os "*****" vários sistemas fazem isto, só não sei qual abordagem é a mais assertiva nesse caso, sobre a questão de identificar quando deve  alterar a senha é simples, se alguém der um foco nela eu apago para que ele possa digitar uma nova e se não mexer não altera...

Comment: @Sanção então eles colocam uma quantidade fixa, independente do tamanho da senha ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues exatamente, mas deixar o campo vazio é o mais utilizado, verifique por exemplo o formulário de alterar senha aqui do SOpt

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues o administrador não deve mesmo conhecer a senha, apenas o usuário deve saber sua própria senha. O administrador pode alterar a senha da mesma forma que o próprio usuário resetaria. A senha anterior é 'esquecida' e uma nova é atribuida.
Mas quando me referi a método, estava falando o de criptografia, nesse caso indico que use o BCrypt. Leia mais nessa pergunta do SOpt: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura

Comment: Não faz diferença alguma inserir os asteriscos. Não importa o que o site X ou site Y faz.. Normalmente, site sério que faz isso coloca meramente alguns asteriscos para ilustrar.  É meramente visual mas não tem necessidade alguma. E outro ponto que comentaram, não dê nenhuma chance de pista que leve a um hacker a entender como é a senha. Se o sujeito sabe que a senha tem 5 ou 8 caracteres, fica menos complicado de quebrar a senha pois nem vai perder tempo com outros tamanhos, entendeu?

Comment: @DanielOmine, entendi, as respostas conseguiram responder estas dúvidas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Teria alguma forma de saber a quantidade de caracteres que eram antes de fazer o md5() ?

De forma segura não! Independente da criptografia que você for usar *md5*, *sha1* ou *sha256* trazer a hash para o cliente não seria uma boa forma de resolver o problema.

### Existe uma abordagem melhor ?

O Comentário do `@Sanção`  trás 2 abordagens:

### 1 - Deixe os campos vazios.

Caso o usuário digite algo você entenderá pela quantidade de caracteres no campo que é para fazer um update.

### 2 - Defina uma quantidade fixa de caracteres.

Caso o usuário de um *focus* nos caracteres apague-os e deixe ele digitar a nova senha.

**Edit**

Você pode dar um placeholder no input, é semelhante a tela de login do nosso http://pt.stackoverflow.com:

```html
<label>Digite sua Senha:</label>
<br>
<input type="password" placeholder="******* Nova senha" size="25">
<br>
<input type="password" placeholder="******* Confirmar senha" size="25">
```

Comment: +1  Exatamente,  qualquer criptografia  vai retornar uma has diferente, eu quero apenas uma forma de poder exibir para o cliente os asteriscos!

Comment: Entendi, no caso, use a segunda abordagem!

Answer (score 4):

Não há como saber a quantidade de caracteres de uma hash md5, justamente porque ela é de mão única, e esse é seu propósito.

Uma forma de saber quanto era antes seria salvar essa quantidade em um campo da base de dados, o que é **complemente inviável na questão de segurança**.

Veja o exemplo de alguns sites de banco, você digita sua senha no input que vai somente até 5 caracteres e não exibe mais nada que você digitar após o 5º digito, mesmo sendo apenas asteriscos, ou o exemplo do Linux, que simplesmente não mostra sua senha enquanto você está digitando.

Você poderia fazer como já foi sugerido anteriormente, colocar uma quantidade fixa no seu input e quando o usuário clicar, zerar o campo, seria a solução mais prática e também a mais usada.

Procure também mudar seu método de criptografia para usar um salt+senha, e depois gerar um hash usando SHA512, é mais indicado do que usar apenas md5 e correr o risco de sua senha ser encontrada em uma tabela arco-íris.

E **nunca use o nome do usuário como salt**.

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível voltar o md5. Não de uma maneira prática e rápida.

Não sei porque quer exibir dessa forma, mas nas minhas telas de usuário não mostro o campo senha. Apenas um link "Alterar senha" que abre um modal.

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível de forma prática. E, se for possível para você, é porque é possível para atacantes externos. Se você viu alguém fazendo, essa pessoa não está levando a segurança a sério.

A propósito, **NÃO USE MD5**! MD5 é demonstradamente falho para o propósito de segurança. Prefira SHA256, pois mesmo o SHA1 já está sendo abandonado por razões de segurança.

Comment: Uma senha "12345" codificada em SHA256 ou SHA2 ou SHA+QualquerCoisa é tão insegura quanto "12345" em MD5.

Comment: Sim, com certeza. Senhas comuns são a primeira coisa que um atacante vai tentar usar. Assim como palavras de dicionário. Mas isso não invalida a preocupação com um algoritmo de hash forte. Não é só porque não dá pra ter 100% de segurança que a gente vai aceitar 0%.

Comment: A preocupação com o tipo do hash é valida quando o brute force é aplicável. Por isso não é 100% certo afirmar, sem explicar os detalhes, que o MD5 é inseguro e deve-se migrar para outros hashes. Dicionários e rainbowtables não incluem salts. Se a senha possuir salt ou um reforço com concatenação, já torna uma rainbow table ou dicionário inválidos. O hacker teria que ter acesso ao salt e gerar uma rainbow table específica desse salt. Se um hacker tem acesso ao DB, ao salt e tudo mais, oras... a falha de segurança não está no hash usado.. né rsrsrs

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, respondendo à pergunta. Sim é possível, se o valor de entrada for igual ao valor existente no banco de dados antes de ser criptografado.

Criptografando o valor de entrada e comparado ao valor já existente, consegue-se o mesmo retorno.

```
function senha($arg){
    $md5 = md5($arg, true);
    return substr($md5, 0, 22);
}

print senha('1234');
print "<br/>";
print senha('1234');

$senha_armazenada = senha('1234');
if($senha_armazenada === senha('1234')){
    print "senha confere";        
} else {
    print "senha nao confere";        
}
```

Contudo funções criptográficas como `md5, sha1` e por adiante, são consideradas impróprias para tarefas como estas, por serem *"fáceis"* de quebrar. Apesar de parecerem indestrutíveis, atualmente existe imenso poder de processamento e imensas técnicas para se obter o verdadeiro valor dessa hash.

Para criar uma `hash` segura, atualmente existem 2 importantes fatores a ter em conta:

- O custo (tempo que o computador vai levar a gerar essa hash).
- O salt (um incremento único, que torna as hash únicas para cada caso).

O `PHP >= 5.5.0` possui [funções nativas](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) para criar, verificar hashes seguras, sem muito esforço. Para versões mais antigas `PHP < 5.5.0`, existem formas de obter o mesmo resultado, também explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85383/problema-com-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-senha-de-usu%C3%A1rio-php-mysql-crypt/85473#85473).

Em vez de usar `md5`, podes usar  as funções nativas do `PHP >= 5.5.0` para criar algo mais seguro.

```
<?php

header("Contet-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8;");

$usuarios = array(
    0 => array(
        'id'=>1,
        'nome'=>'Edilson',
        'hash'=>'$2y$10$i260FJQg7VgsNjXl6s9Mje9aqXUGbfa9L/c8bA2NOUHyDVoyJoyQu'
        ),
    1 => array(
        'id'=>1,
        'nome'=>'Samuel',
        'hash'=>'$2y$10$r1wD4rLLgB1jm6ExF.Em5eyKXdK4Wn8f6z.G9fsxmc3xXay4.pI/O'
        )    
    );


function logar($usuario, $senha){
    global $usuarios;
    foreach($usuarios as $key=>$set){
        if(in_array($usuario, $set)){
            if(password_verify($senha, $set['hash'])){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function cadastrar($usuario, $senha){
    global $usuarios;
    if(!empty($usuario) && !empty($senha)){
        $hash = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $id = mt_rand(3,50);
        if(array_push($usuarios, array('id'=>$id, 'nome'=>$usuario, 'hash'=>$hash))){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//var_dump(cadastrar('Edilson','password')); # (true/cadastrado)
var_dump(logar('Edilson', 'password')); # (true/logado)
var_dump(logar('Samuel', '1234')); # (true/logado)print_r($usuarios);

?>
```

Aqui por exemplo, a variável `$usuarios` funciona como uma tabela no banco de dados, e quando a função `logado` é chamada, ela procura nessa array, a hash correspondente, e compara, atravez da função `password_verify`, que retorna true caso as duas sejam sejam iguais, ou false, caso falhe a comparação.

## Recomendado:

- [Hash de senha segura](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Answer (score 1):

O `md5()` é irreversível, a senha criptografada não é acessível, a quantidade de caracteres sempre será 32, o rash do **md5** pode se repetir mesmo que tenham senhas de diferentes caracteres. Uma das maneiras seguras de criar senhas é através do [**password_hash**](http://php.net/function.password-hash) do php.net.

```
<?php
require 'password.php';

$passwordHash = password_hash('secret-password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (password_verify('bad-password', $passwordHash)) {
    //Senha correta
} else {
    //Senha errada
}
```

A consulta para um MD5 sempre será através de uma senha válida do tipo:

```
'SELECT * FROM TABELA where senha=MD5(:senha)'
```